# Cors error when using `GenerateSignedPostPolicyV4` to upload a file in Google Cloud Storage

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, pre-signed-url

I am working on using a [signed URL](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls) in Cloud Storage to allow clients to upload files directly to Cloud Storage.

Because I want to limit the maximum size of files that users can upload to GCS, I am thinking of using [policy document](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/authentication/signatures#policy-document) to control the upload behavior by using `content-length-range` condition. I am using [GenerateSignedPostPolicyV4](https://pkg.go.dev/cloud.google.com/go/storage#hdr-Post_Policy_V4_Signed_Request) to generate the post policy document.

The setup that I have works perfectly fine if I build HTML form based on post policy document which is generated by `GenerateSignedPostPolicyV4`.

Below is a copy of the [sample form](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/post-object-forms#usage_and_examples) that works fine for me.

```
<form action="https://storage.googleapis.com/[MY_BUCKET_NAME]/" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input name="content-type" value="application/octet-stream" type="hidden">
    <input name="key" value="test" type="hidden">
    <input name="policy" value="[MY_POLICY]" type="hidden">
    <input name="x-goog-algorithm" value="GOOG4-RSA-SHA256" type="hidden">
    <input name="x-goog-credential" value="[MY_CREDENTIAL]" type="hidden">
    <input name="x-goog-date" value="20210624T194049Z" type="hidden">
    <input name="x-goog-signature" value="[MY_SIGNATURE]" type="hidden">
    <input type="file" name="file"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload File" name="submit"><br>
</form>
```

Now, I have single page application and would like to complete the upload programmatically if possible in JavaScript/TypeScript without using HTML form. For instance, I want to upload files using `fetch` or `xhr` instead of using standard HTML form.

Strangely, when I use `xhr` or `fetch` to make `POST` request, I am encountering `CORS` error. I do have `CORS` properly set up in my bucket because if I use the standard [SignedUrl](https://pkg.go.dev/cloud.google.com/go/storage#hdr-Signed_URLs) to generate URL & upload the file with the `PUT` method, the upload works fine through `xhr` or `fetch`, which proves that CORS is set up properly in my bucket.

(My cors look like below)

```
[{"maxAgeSeconds": 3600, "method": ["PUT", "POST"], "origin": ["*"], "responseHeader": ["Content-Type", "Access-Control-Allow-Origin"]}]
```

But.. since you can't enforce file size limit with `PUT` upload, using `PUT` `xhr/fetch` is not an option for me.

So my question is, is required to use html form to upload data to GCS if I use `post policy doc` based upload? Is there any reason why GCS decided to enforce CORS for this type of submission?

Comment: I ended up using `PUT` method with regular `SignedUrl` with this specific header `x-goog-content-length-range` to limit file size while uploading a file through xhr/fetch. More info on https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/reference-headers#xgoogcontentlengthrange

Comment: probably its worth it if you could share how you implemented this to surpass the CORS error as it can be useful for other people trying to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When uploading an object (file) to Google Cloud Storage using a [Signed Url](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls), `PUT` file size limits are indeed enforceable.

This is achieved by setting the HTTP Header `x-goog-content-length-range` (find docs [here](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/reference-headers#xgoogcontentlengthrange)), and specifying the byte range within you want the Signed URL to allow. For example:

```
"x-goog-content-length-range":"0,24117249"
```

This specifies that files that are uploaded to that URL will be accepted, starting from the size of 0B (bytes) to 23MB (24117249 Bytes).

You have to use this header both when creating the signed URL, and when accessing that URL aka uploading the file.

---

**EDIT**:

In response to [Martin Zeitler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/549372/martin-zeitler)'s comment, I have done some more research on the topic, and have managed to get a somewhat working script using Signed URLs with Resumable Uploads.

How does it work? Firstly, we create the `POST` method Signed URL with a header instructing the bucket to initiate a resumable upload operation, which in exchange responds with a `Location` header with the URI to which we have to send the file with a `PUT` request.

You want to have set your credentials prior to starting the server. Learn more about how to do so [here](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production).

However, in order to get the required permissions both to call the signed URL and to upload the file to the bucket, we need an **access token**. You can get it [here](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/). You can also [learn more about OAuth2 Authentication](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2). This access token does not have to be the same when getting the upload URI and uploading; however, for simplicity reasons I decided to keep it the same.

The script in itself is **not something you would want to use in production**: it was solely made for illustration purposes.

(you need the `flask` and `google-cloud-storage` Python libraries for this to work)

**main.py**:

```py
from flask import Flask, render_template
import datetime, requests
from google.cloud import storage
#----------------------------------------------------------------------
#----------------------------------------------------------------------
def generate_upload_signed_url_v4(bucket_name, blob_name):
    storage_client = storage.Client()
    bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name) #Sets name of the target bucket
    blob = bucket.blob(blob_name) #Sets the filename our object will have once uploaded to the bucket
    headers = {
        "x-goog-resumable":"start", #Needed for creating a resumable upload: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/reference-headers#xgoogresumable
    }
    url = blob.generate_signed_url(
        version="v4",
        expiration=datetime.timedelta(minutes=15),
        headers=headers,
        method="POST",
    )
    return url
#----------------------------------------------------------------------
#----------------------------------------------------------------------
bucket_name = 'sample-bucket' #INSERT YOUR BUCKET NAME HERE
blob_name = 'your-desired-filename' #INSERT THE NAME OF THE FILE HARE
url = generate_upload_signed_url_v4(bucket_name,blob_name) #Instantiates the Signed URL to get the Session ID to upload the file

app = Flask(__name__) #Flask

token = "access-token" #Insert access token here
headers = { #Must have the same headers used in the generation of the Signed URL + the Authorization header
    "Authorization":f"Bearer {token}",
    "x-goog-resumable":"start",
}
#Get Session ID from the `Location` response header and store it in the `session_url` variable
r = requests.post(url, data="", headers=headers)
if r.status_code == requests.codes.created:
    session_url = r.headers["Location"]
else:
    session_url = "None"
#----------------------------------------------------------------------
#----------------------------------------------------------------------
@app.route("/gcs",methods=["PUT","GET","POST"])
def main():
    return render_template("index.html",token=token,url=session_url) # Sends token and session_url to the template

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True,port=8080,host="0.0.0.0") #Starts the server on port 8080 and sets the host to 0.0.0.0 (available to the internet)
```

**templates/index.html** (learn more [here](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/quickstart/#rendering-templates) about Flask Templates):

```html
<html>
   <head>
   </head>
   <body>
      <input type="file" id="fileinput" />
      <script>
         // Select your input type file and store it in a variable
         const input = document.getElementById('fileinput');
         
         // This will upload the file after having read it
         const upload = (file) => {
                 fetch('{{ url }}', { // Your PUT endpoint -> On this case, the Session ID URL retrieved by the Signed URL
         method: 'PUT',
         body: file, 
         headers: {
         "Authorization": "Bearer {{ token }}", //I don't think it's a good idea to have this publicly available.
         "x-goog-content-length-range":"0,24117249" //Having this on the front-end may allow users to tamper with your system.
         }
         }).then(
         response => response.text()
         ).then(str => (new window.DOMParser()).parseFromString(str, "text/xml")
         ).then(data => console.log(data) //Prints response sent from server in an XML format
         ).then(success => console.log(success) // Handle the success response object
         ).catch(
         error => console.log(error) // Handle the error response object
         );
         };
         
         const onSelectFile = () => upload(input.files[0]);
         
         input.addEventListener('change', onSelectFile, false); //Whenever a  file is selected, the EventListener is triggered and executes the `onSelectFile` function
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

Now we have to configure the [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) settings for our bucket. We have to allow our server by changing the `origin` value. Then, we have to explicitly state what HTTP headers and the methods we want to allow.  **A CORS error will be thrown if this is not properly set.**

**cors.json**:

```json
[
  {
    "origin": ["http://<your-ip-here>:<yourport-here>"],
    "responseHeader": [
      "Content-Type",
      "Authorization",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
      "X-Upload-Content-Length",
      "X-Goog-Resumable",
      "x-goog-content-length-range"
    ],
    "method": ["PUT", "OPTIONS","POST"],
    "maxAgeSeconds": 3600
  }
]
```

Once properly configured, we can apply this configuration to our bucket using the command

`gsutil cors set <name-of-configfile> gs://<name-of-bucket>`

To try this, go to your browser and enter this url:`http://<your-ip>:<your-port>/gcs`.

Select a file of your choice (Under 23MB or the upper bound you may set), and observe how it does actually upload to your bucket.

Now you may want to try uploading a file greater than the upper bound set on the `x-goog-content-length-range` header, and observe how the upload fails with an `EntityTooLarge` error.

Comment: Not sure if this is accurate, because it needs an initial `POST` and a subsequent `PUT` for resumable uploads: "Since the session URI acts as an authentication token, the PUT requests do not use any signed URLs" ...I mean, ho about e. resumable uploads with a limit to be defined? The initial request has to be `POST` and this usually would be the only request issued.

Comment: Edited the answer in response to your comment.